Pulling URLs containing a certain data with IMPORTXML
Trying to pull out URL containing a number from the cell B2 on the link from the cell A2.
With this formula I am getting an error. I assume the error lies within contains?
The link for reference - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gFwJ16dI19zRm7gce0hL481337TtnAOSJ3ETKt38czY/edit?usp=sharing
I am using the formula =IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href[contains(.,'B2')]")


I am using the formula =IMPORTXML(A3,"//a/@href[contains(.,'B2')]")

Your link needs an access....

Sorry for confusion, I updated the link

At your showing formula =IMPORTXML(A3,"//a/@href[contains(.,'B2')]"), it seems that the cell value of "A3" is empty. Is this related to your current issue? And, can I ask you the value that you want to retrieve from the URL of https://sssss.sss/?

my bad, it is supposed to be A2

Can you try this formula? (You need to have a valid URL in cell A2)
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href"),XMATCH("*" & B2 & "*",IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href"),2))


It gives an error Error
Function SUM parameter 1 expects number values. But '' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

i updated the spreadsheet with a real website

If the search value is a number, it works.... see your test sheet please

I revised the formula above and updated your test sheet. It should now work either the search value is numeric or string. If it's OK for you, you can accept the answer.
